# How to change CPU scaling driver to intel_pstate

Tags: drivers, intel, cpu

I have an iMac with an **Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU 870 @ 2.93GHz (1 physical, 4 cores, 8 threads)**

I am on **Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS**

I was trying miscellaneous stuff (most of which I don't even remember) in an effort to change the CPU frequency because it was always fixed to 1.2GHz (minimum).

Currently the acpi-cpufreq driver is used:

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver
acpi-cpufreq
acpi-cpufreq
acpi-cpufreq
acpi-cpufreq
acpi-cpufreq
acpi-cpufreq
acpi-cpufreq
acpi-cpufreq
```

and **I want to switch back to `intel_pstate`** but I don't know how to achieve this.

When trying to switch to `acpi-cpufreq` I added the kernel parameter `intel_pstate=disable` in my */etc/default/grub*. I removed it and I did execute `sudo update-grub` but after reboot I still get that `acpi-cpufreq` is the scaling driver.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

GENERAL ANSWER:

Open terminal and type:
`sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
Then find line:
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
And change it to:
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="intel_pstate=enable quiet splash"`
Save file and run following command:
`sudo update-grub`
Restart system and check is it enabled by:
`sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver`

ANSWER FOR INTEL PROCCESORS BEFORE 2nd GEN:

I am sorry but you can not use intel_pstate on your proccesor. It is only compactiable with proccesors from Sandy Bridge(2nd) generation up. You can only use old CPUfreq with Intel i7 870
EXTRA INFO:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.12/admin-guide/pm/intel_pstate.html

Comment: I already removed the parameter and updated grub but without any luck.

Comment: I tried that too (`intel_pstate=enabled`) but it didn't work either.

Comment: @V.H. could you please add some references to your answer? Something like [ArchLinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling#CPU_frequency_driver) or similar.